base-independent representation of numbers as a ternary-tree
There is the concept of a super-prime OEIS A006450 which is a prime whose index/subscript is another prime number.
E.g 11 is the 5th prime number and 5 is prime. 31 is the 11th prime number.
[OEIS A38580] (https://oeis.org/A380580) even shows primes with an index that is a prime whose index is a prime...
Inspired by this I wondered if we could take this one step further...
Every natural number has a unique prime factorization:
$$n = {p_1}^{n_1}{p_2}^{n_2}...{p_k}^{n_k}$$
We can break down this expression further by repeatedly primefactorizing all non-zero numbers occuring in it in the manner above. And by numbers I mean exponents AND indices.
$$n = {p_{p_{p^{...}...}}}^{p_{p^{p_{...}}p_{p_{...}...}}}$$
Once we are done factorizing the only prime left in the expression is $p_1 = 2$. So a tree with nodes $p$ and leafs $p_1$  will emerge. It is a ternary (at most three children for every parent) tree as for every node (symbolizing a prime as a factor of an exponent, index or primefactor of $n$) there at most three branches (subscript $i$,multiplication,exponent $n_i$
Finally to really (graphically) make a tree out of it you could replace p and {p_1} by simple nodes, dots and branch according to this ruleset (rootnode on the very left and growing to the right)

exponentiate the prime(top)
multiply another prime (straight)
add an index to the prime (down)

Examples:
$$42 = {p_1}{p_2}{p_4} = {p_1}{p_{p_1}}{p_{{p_1}^{p_1}}}$$
$$123456 = {p_1}^6{p_{117}} = {p_1}^{{p_1}{p_2}}{p_{{p_2}^{p_1}{p_6}}} = {p_1}^{{p_1}{p_{p_1}}}{p_{{p_{p_1}}^{p_1}{{p_1}{p_{p_1}}}}}$$
I'm asking if anyone here can give me some references about this. The closest thing maybe super-primes but could there be connections to other problems regarding prime numbers?
Also I would like to investigate this concept a bit because it provides really the only base-independent way of displaying a number that I'm aware of. Although it would be completely impractical.
Can anyone think of interesting questions to ask about this unique ternary-tree?
One would be:
What is the average number of leafs in the ternary-tree representation of natural numbers below n?

what is the index of a prime? define it.

The i-th prime has index i. So e.g. 11 has index 5, 23 has index 9 and so on...
